# Is there a non-prefixed input placeholder pseudo-element?

Tags: html, css, standards

I'm using this good old snippet to style input placeholder text:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
  color: transparent;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  color: transparent;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  color: transparent;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  color: transparent;
}
```

And I'm seeing examples of a "standard", but can't tell if there actually exists one.

For example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-placeholder includes this example:

```
input[placeholder] { text-overflow: ellipsis; }
```

But that's a completely different rule than `:-moz-placeholder`. Selecting any input with a placeholder attribute, and not the placeholder pseudo-element.

I also see references to `::placeholder` https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/
But I can't tell if that actually exists.

Comment: The idea is that one day, probably when pigs fly and hell freezes over, we can live in a world without `prefixes`.

Comment: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Don't know if it helps, bu here you are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there wasn't a standard at the time these implementations began popping up. Every vendor was figuring it out on their own. Hence either pseudo-elements or pseudo-classes, or in the case of Firefox, a breaking change from one to the other.

Now that we have a bunch of completely different and incompatible implementations, it's understandably difficult to converge them into a standard that everyone can agree on. For starters, a pseudo-element and a pseudo-class do completely different things — from an author's perspective it would seem that the ideal scenario is to have *both*: a pseudo-class for styling input elements that have placeholder text, and a pseudo-element for styling the placeholder text itself. Needless to say, current implementations and documentation don't necessarily match those expectations either.

The good news is that the standardization process has already kicked off, for *both* of these things:

- [Selectors 4 introduces a `:placeholder-shown` pseudo-class](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#placeholder) for matching elements with placeholder text where said placeholder text is currently being displayed
- [The FPWD of Pseudo-Elements 4 introduces a `::placeholder` pseudo-element](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-pseudo-4/#placeholder-pseudo) for styling the placeholder text itself

The naming process is minuted [here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Feb/0393.html). Now all that's left is to wait a couple of months or years for vendors to figure out the rest.